# Does ZFC pin down precisely which theorems PA can and cannot prove?

Tags: logic, set-theory

We can show (in $\mathrm{ZFC})$ that $\mathrm{PA}$ has a model. Thus:

$$\mathrm{ZFC} \vdash (\mathrm{PA} \not\vdash \bot)$$

This is probably a silly question, but is it true that for all sentences $\phi$ in the language of $\mathrm{PA}$, we have the following? $$(\mathrm{ZFC} \vdash (\mathrm{PA} \vdash \phi)) \vee (\mathrm{ZFC} \vdash (\mathrm{PA} \not\vdash \phi))$$

I'm guessing "no."

Comment: @user8268 : your answer (deleted) was correct. ZFC is a true theory (it has an $\omega$ model), and it is an effective theory. So if the question above had a positive answer then there would be a computable completion of PA, which there is not. Hence the question above has a negative answer.

Comment: @CarlMummert: thanks a lot - but if I can ask you, please write the answer. Now I feel a bit lost in the murky waters of logic.

Comment: This comment develops (just a bit) Carl's comment. It is easy to prove from the assumption that "for all sentences $\phi$ in the language of PA, it holds that either $ZFC \vdash (PA \vdash \phi)$ or $ZFC \vdash (PA \not \vdash \phi)$" (together with assuming that $ZFC$ is consistent) that there is an algorithm to compute "provability in PA". The algorithm is the trivial one you expect (use provability in ZFC until you find the proof that shows ...). Using the well-known fact that PA is non-computable one concludes that the answer to your question is NO.

Comment: @user8268: yes, the methods in my answer can easily turn confusing until you get used to them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, if ZFC were inconsistent then the answer would trivially be "yes", so the question is only of interest if ZFC is consistent. I will freely use the consistency of ZFC for the rest of the answer.

In that case, the answer is "no".

It is a standard fact in computability theory that PA is an "effectively inseparable" theory. This means that if we let $$V = \{ \phi : PA \vdash \phi\}$$ and $$U = \{ \phi : PA \vdash \lnot \phi\}$$ then there is no computable "separating set" $C$ with $V \subseteq C$ and $C \cap U = \emptyset$. (Both $U$ and $V$ are r.e. sets because PA is an effective theory; inseparability implies among other things that neither of them is computable).

Note that (*): if $PA \vdash \phi$ then $ZFC \vdash \ulcorner PA \vdash \phi\urcorner$. This is because if we have a derivation of $\phi$ in PA we can convert it to a derivation of $\ulcorner PA \vdash \phi\urcorner$ in ZFC.

Now let $$S = \{\phi : ZFC \vdash \ulcorner PA \vdash \phi\urcorner\}.$$ Then $S$ is an r.e. set also, and $V \subseteq S$ because of (*). Moreover, $U \cap S = \emptyset$. Suppose otherwise - then there would be a $\phi$ such that $ZFC\vdash \ulcorner PA \vdash \phi \urcorner$ and $PA \vdash \lnot \phi$. But then, using (*), $ZFC \vdash \ulcorner PA \vdash \lnot \phi\urcorner$. But ZFC proves 
$$
\lnot(\ulcorner PA \vdash \phi\urcorner \land \ulcorner PA \vdash \lnot \phi\urcorner)
$$
because ZFC proves PA is consistent (e.g. Gentzen's consistency proof goes through formalized in ZFC). Therefore, because ZFC is consistent, $U \cap S$ is empty.

If the question had a positive answer, $S$ would be computable. The algorithm would be: given $\phi$, enumerate derivations in ZFC until you find a derivation of $\ulcorner PA \vdash \phi\urcorner$ or a derivation of $\lnot \ulcorner PA \vdash \phi\urcorner$. An affirmative answer to the question says this search will always terminate, and since ZFC is consistent exactly one of the two options will happen. Then we can tell whether $\phi \in S$ by seeing which option occurs.

So, in summary, if the question had a positive answer then $S$ would be a computable separating set for $V$ and $U$, which is impossible.

Also, for those who are interested, it is not necessary to use the fact that ZFC has an $\omega$-model, just the fact that ZFC is consistent. That should be expected, because effective inseparability is a very strong form of incompleteness.

If we use the fact that ZFC has an $\omega$-model, we get a much shorter argument, as mentioned in the comments. In that case, we have for all $\phi$ that $ZFC \vdash \ulcorner PA \vdash \phi\urcorner$ if and only if $PA \vdash \phi$. Then, if the question had an affirmative answer, we could decide for arbitrary $\phi$ whether $\phi \in V$ by searching for a ZFC derivation of $\ulcorner PA \vdash \phi\urcorner$ or a derivation of $\lnot \ulcorner PA \vdash \phi \urcorner$; the first option would mean $PA \vdash \phi$ and the second would mean $PA \not\vdash \phi$. Since $V$ is not computable, that contradiction means the question has a negative answer. This proof is easier than the one using effective inseparability, because it leverages an extra property of ZFC (having an $\omega$-model, or more specifically $\Sigma^0_1$ soundness) that is not used in the proof by inseparability.

Comment: I have tried to mark everywhere that I use the fact that ZFC is consistent. If there are more places where I have used it silently, please let me know.